# Trying to capture IP addresses in wordpress / php script

Tags: php, wordpress, ip

I would like to keep track of IP addresses visiting my site, as it helps determine what content I should host.

I a really not a programmer, so i was looking for a pre-built solution.

I found this script:

```
<?php
$LogFileLocation = "/public_html/cms/iplog.txt";
$fh = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$LogFileLocation,'at');
fwrite($fh,date('dMy    H:i:s')."\t".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."\t".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']."\n");
fclose($fh);
?>
```

however when i created iplog.txt and browse to it, nothing happens.

Comment: http://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/show-visitor-ip-address.0.1.zip

Comment: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tags/tracking

Comment: *"Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people who write code because they love it."*

Comment: what do you mean nothing happens, no file? empty file?

Comment: i dont want to echo the ip address, i want to capturing it when people visit certain pages of the website

Comment: @ in god, yes the file is completly empty

Comment: "i dont want to echo the ip address"... but look at how those plugins are doing it and adapt.

Answer (score 0):

If you need only statistic of visiting of your site why you don't use Google Analitics (http://www.google.com/analytics/)? It gives full information on how to track visits onto the site. Your method gives you only text file with date, user's ip and page which user visited; but if you aren't a programmer, you will not sort this information and operated this data.
If you still decide to use your method of store information and don't want to use Google Analitics, then save data about user and visited pages in the database in special created table (id, date, ip, uri). This method will permit show date-statistic, statistic for ip and single page.

Answer (score 0):

You can capture IP of the visitor with the following code.
`$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];`

Now you can store it in your database. For that you have to create a column in your database table that stores the ip address. Along with IP address, you can store many other information in the database for keeping track of users like time stamp, duration, page visits etc. There are many tools available like Google Analytic and others which provide you such services free of cost but they don't store the record in your website's database. So choose accordingly.